# Retrieve neighbour data by using recursive sql query

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

[image: Data in table]

This is my table which I keep data for production order. I want to get data by giving @task (e.g. 99537 ) parameter as this,

1. Get Loom number of the @task 
   for 99537  loom number is :101
2. Get all following "ulk" processes till reach another process task with ordering by OrderNo column 
   the "ulk" processes are theese for 101 loom  after 99537 task is: 100127,99829

Here is the [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/964ab/2)

How to write a CTE query for this? 
if CTE not possible, any solution also possible.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What exactly is the required output for the sample case stated in your question?

Comment: Why didn't the plethora of examples already available on the internet help you?

Comment: sorry for complex explanation. There is an sqlfiddle link in my question. if you will look at to the result I need just top 2 rows with shown order.

Comment: What if there are no `'ulk'` processes immediately after the selected Task?

Comment: Tab Alleman I its not just CTE problem, I also need to retrieve data till another flag..

Comment: Giorgos Betsos, that case it will return NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT OrderNo, WeavingLoom, Task, Process
FROM (
SELECT g1.OrderNo, g1.WeavingLoom, g1.Task, g1.Process, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY g1.OrderNo) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Process ORDER BY g1.OrderNo) AS grp
FROM GanttTable AS g1
INNER JOIN (SELECT OrderNo, WeavingLoom
            FROM GanttTable
            WHERE Task = 99537) AS g2
ON g1.WeavingLoom = g2.WeavingLoom AND g1.OrderNo > g2.OrderNo) AS t
WHERE grp = 0 AND Process = 'ulk'
```

`grp` field identifies islands of consecutive records having the same `Process` value. The very first island, i.e. the group of records immediately following the selected-by-TaskID record, has `grp=0`. If this slice of records happens also to have `Process = 'ulk'` then it is returned by the above query, otherwise no rows are returned.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/964ab/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfect, even without cte! Now I am thinking on it